# jquery, parse partial text input to formatted html output?

Tags: jquery, regex, parsing, input, textarea

I'm looking at a very small amount of code:

```
var val = $("#id_input").val();
$("#output").text(val);
```

Which essentially takes the input into a field, `<textarea id="id_input"></textarea>`, and outputs it, exactly as it is.

What I'm trying to do is turn input newlines that begin with a `-` into output `<ul><li></li></ul>` on my site....

The approach I've been going at is to split the input by lines and then concatenate them, after passing each line through this:

```
function startsWith(string, pattern) {
  return string.slice(0, pattern.length) == pattern;
}

show(startsWith("-"));
```

I feel like there's a more standard approach though?  For example, I've read other posts on StackOverflow that use a `find` function to produce similar results.  I'm suspicious of these because there's no actual regex.  It seems too good to be true.

[image]

In the image, you can see that green text is `comments`, white text is `input`, and black text is `output`.

I understand that there are existing technologies that have this functionality, but they come with a lot of other functionality.  I'm trying to create an input that isolates this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a start that you can tweak yourself: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acheong87/ykVEw/).

I did it in two replacements, first to add the `<ul></ul>`, and next to add the `<li></li>`s. (Doing it in one step would've been easier if JavaScript supported lookbehind assertions; without them it's still possible but messy.)

```
    val = val.replace(/((?:(?:^|[\n\r]+)[\t ]*-[\t ]*[^\n\r]*)+)/g, "\n<ul>\n$1\n</ul>");
    val = val.replace(/[\n\r]+[\t ]*-[\t ]*([^\n\r]*)/g, "\n  <li>$1</li>");
```

I made some assumptions while constructing this, which you may have to undo:

1. Treat series of newlines as one newline.
2. Remove spaces and tabs before and after the `-`.

The following input,

```
hello, world.
- two
- things
hi, again.
- three
 -more 
-things
```

creates the following output:

```
hello, world.
<ul>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>things</li>
</ul>
hi, again.
<ul>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>more </li>
  <li>things</li>
</ul>
```

**EXPLANATION**

The first regex simply identifies a *set* of list items.

```
(                   Captured group ($1).

    (?:             Group (one list item). -------------------+
                                                              |
        (?:         Group (for alternation). ---------+       |
                                                      |       |
            ^       Start-of-string                   |       |
                                                      |       |
            |           OR                      <-----+       |
                                                              |
            [\n\r]+     one or more newlines.                 |
                                                              |
        )                                                     |
                                                              |
        [\t ]*      (Ignore tabs and spaces.)                 |
        -           (Dash.)                                   |
        [\t ]*      (Ignore tabs and spaces.)                 |
                                                              |
        [^\n\r]*    List item text (everything but newlines). |
                                                              |
    )                                                         |
    +               One or more list items. <-----------------+

)
```

This *set* of list items, captured in `$1`, is wrapped in `<ul></ul>` tags:

```
"\n<ul>\n$1\n</ul>"
```

The second regex wraps each list item in `<li></li>` tags, and is very similar to the first, so it may be more useful to show what has changed:

```
first regex  : /((?:(?:^|[\n\r]+)[\t ]*-[\t ]* [^\n\r]* )+)/g
differences  :  xxxxxxxxx       x             (        )xxx
second regex : /         [\n\r]+ [\t ]*-[\t ]*([^\n\r]*)   /g
```

In words,

1. we no longer care about the *set* of list items, only *each* list item, so we can drop the non-capturable group that was used for quantifying, `(?:...)+`,
2. after the first regex substitution (which prepends a `\n<ul>\n`), it should be impossible for a list item to begin at the start of the string, so we can drop the alternation, `(?:^|...)`,
3. however we are now interested in capturing the list item text, so we add a capturing group, `(...)`.

Comment: It's definitely a strong start.  I'm trying to orchestrate it with my other code, now, which is seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/5ZXnx/.  I haven't been able to do that yet, but I can see that there's a strong overlap.  When I think jquery, I always think 'instantaneous'/'no refresh'/'preview', you know?  I'll be back in an hour or two to let you know if I've been able to adapt it.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 - Hm, you may have seen my original version, where I used the ``change`` event, but if you refresh, the latest version uses ``keyup``, so there is instantaneous updating as-you-type. Also, I noticed a bug caused by the second pair of ``\s*`` in each expression; they had to be replaced by ``[\t ]``.

Comment: Thank you.  I really hurried to get back, but I had a lot of clients come into the shop, this morning.  I really appreciate the effort you put into this answer, upkeeping it to match the desired result, and showing multiple versions.  I will let you know if I have further questions.

Comment: The only issue is that the first line isn't handled.  XD  Isn't the regex for the start of a string in an input box `^`?  So, the search pattern `^-` like, `|^-` (or string start), belongs, right?

Comment: Oh, good point. Yeah, you've got the idea. I couldn't think of an elegant way to incorporate this, though. See edited solution...

Comment: Would you mind if I edited your solution to add a section beneath the regex much like the answer which was deleted, to break down the regex into comprehensible human English?  I know that a lot of programmers, even late in the game, have trouble with regex; so, I feel it's very important that an answer have a clear regex explanation.  Alternatively, I can try to explain it as a part of the question: just retroactively append it, like I had the regex from the start (which I didn't). ^^

Comment: No, I wouldn't mind, but also I'd be glad to add an explanation myself later tonight--usually I break out the ASCII art but was too busy yesterday. Feel free to do it yourself too if you would like, though. Appreciate your active interest in bettering the question/answer for the community.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, to save you some typing.  Then, you can correct it tonight?  I'm very bad at regex, but I'm good at formatting things and will have a good guess for everything.  Actually I have many questions along these same lines.  Regex is a beast.  On Monday, I'm going to be talking with an instructor about all this stuff.

Comment: (I have time now; but I don't wanna start an explanation if you're working on one; let me know.)

Comment: Why do you use a double non-capture at the beginning: `(?:(?:`?

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 - Explanation added. To answer your question though, I needed one group to encapsulate "one or more {list items}", i.e. ``(...)+``, and one group to encapsulate "start-of-string OR newlines", i.e. ``(^|[\n\r]+)``, and since I don't need them to be captured (i.e. into ``$2`` and ``$3``), I made them non-capturable. I could have left them capturable; it wouldn't have mattered. I just like to explicitly make any group I don't use, non-capturable.

Comment: So, a double negative doesn't equal a positive?  Interesting.  Actually, I noticed one more thing: the \n in the first replacement pattern, after `$1` is not very useful, right?  There are some other things that might be useful to note to others (for example, the `<pre>` tag in the html causes the html code to show; in the original jsfiddle, it was to get proper word wrapping).

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 - It's always interesting to see how new eyes perceive things! It seems you view the ``?:`` as a "not" of some sort, thus you see ``?:?:`` as "not not". Instead, think of ``(?: ... )`` as an entirely different kind of brackets, separate from ``( ... )``. Why the language designers chose ``(?: ... )``, I'm not sure. As for the ``\n``, nope, not useful; I added the ``\n``s so the output in the ``<pre></pre>`` would look nice in jsFiddle.

Comment: I picked that up from regexpal.com's quick reference.

Comment: @Archeong87 I'm also curious, why does it output with the code showing, rather than in formatted html?  Ah, it's because you use `.text` and not `.html`.

Answer (score 5):

```
uls = val.replace(/(^-.*$(?:\n^-.*$)*)/mg, "<ul>\n$1\n</ul>")
lis = uls.replace(/^-(.*)$/mg, '<li>$1</li>')
$("#output").html(val);
```

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ns9eL/1/) what you were looking for?  It's not perfect, but it does the basics.

It works as follows:

```
Surround the would be lists with <ul></ul>
    This works by finding lines that start with a '-' |^-.*$|,
    then matching contiguous, similar lines |(?:\n^-.*$)| 0 or more times |*|
    it uses the multiline (m) and global (g) flags too:
      match ^ and $ at the begining and end of lines (m)
      and get all the ones in the string (g)
    surround them (<ul>\n$1\n</ul>)
Surround the list items with <li></li>
     match lines with a hyphen at the beginning |^-(.*)$|
     surround them (<li>$1</li>)
```

Comment: Thank you.  The explanation is very clear.  Regex is always a very troublesome topic for new programmers, I think, so I hope that everybody reads your answer.

Comment: You're using `console.log`, and he's used a `keyup` function.  What's the difference?

Comment: Actually, I've also used a key up function (see the html).  The console.log was for when I was debugging it.  Ignore it.

Comment: Actually, I cannot see the changes as having been comitted to your JS fiddle; otherwise, thank you for the explanation of your regex.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ns9eL/3/ - but the only thing I did was remove `console.log`.  If you look up at the html, you'll see the textarea has an `onkeyup` function.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you're dead set on using regular expressions? Although they're nice in that they're efficient and concise, I often find them hard to read if I'm going back to them later.

I would probably approach the problem the same way you did, only I'd wrap each list item in its own list to handle sublists:

```
<ul><li>item 1</li></ul>
<ul><li>item 2</li></ul>
```

Rather than:

```
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Which handles a mix of list and non-list items gracefully. The only reason I **wouldn't** use this approach is if I had to manipulate everything in a list together later on (eg - style the first list but not the second one).

[Example in JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D5uEJ/5/) (thanks to FrankieTheKneeMan for the css for ul's)

Comment: also, target with xpath and such changes when you use `<ul><li>item 1</li></ul>
<ul><li>item 2</li></ul>`